# API Gateway for Powershell scripts

Tags: rest, powershell, api

I would like to be able to call Powershell scripts using a REST API. *(Please note that I am describing the _opposite_ of calling a REST API from Powershell.)*  Are there any prebuilt API gateways that support this use case? I've looked at Ocelot, but it currently only acts as a gateway to other REST APIs. Ideally I would simply design my Powershell script functions to follow a defined interface pattern, put the files into a defined directory, and the API gateway would either immediately make those functions available as REST API calls or with minimal configuration.

EDIT: To clarify, I am looking for something self hosted, not cloud based. I haven't found anything yet that is exactly what I need, I may create something myself.

Answer (score 1):

You can try AWS Lambda and API gateway integration.

Here is an example: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/creating-a-powershell-rest-api/

Amazon offer 12 month free tier plan for this.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I should have clarified that I was looking for something self hosted, rather than cloud based.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of options. If you are on Azure you could expose your Powershell Scripts through Azure Automation :

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-webhooks

That'd be a lightweight way of having your scripts enabled through a HTTP POST scenario.

You could also combine or mix it with adding API Management in front to support various scenarios (adding GET/PUT/DELETE support e.g.) or even automate or proxy more things. API Management could of course also be automated.

- https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/api-management/

You could also create a folder structure with modules & sub-functions and create a full REST API by using Azure Functions with PowerShell:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-powershell

The latter would also be able to execute in containers & in the supported Azure Function 
runtimes.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I should have clarified that I was looking for something self hosted, rather than cloud based.